# Angular 4 disabled FormControl does not check or show validating errors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I have `FormControl` object bind to `input` element.

`<input matInput [formControl]="nameControl">`

It is initialized as follows

`this.nameControl = new FormControl({value: initValue, disabled: true}, [Validators.required, UniqueValueValidator(uniqueValues)]);`

When `FormControl` is disabled, it does not check for any errors.

Question is how do I keep the control disabled and still show the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to get `valid` or `invalid` status when form control is `disabled`.

A form control have four types of status: `pending`, `disabled`, `valid` and `invalid`, and will **only keep one of these status**.
So when form control's status is `disabled`, it will only be `disable`, not `valid`, neither `invalid`, see **[docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disabled)**.

---

Technically you can simulate the validating process but anything based on `input.hasError('...')` or `invalid`/`valid` won't work.

```
<input matInput [formControl]="nameControl">
<div *ngIf="form.get('nameControl').disabled && form.get('nameControl').value === ''">
  field is required.
</div>
```

Comment: But wouldn't there be a requirement to keep a control disabled but still be able to show errors if any. (or in other words how do I keep a control disabled on UI but still be able to show any errors on it)

Comment: @kiranghule27 you can technically simulate the validate process. But IMO that doesn't worth. I have added a sample, see my updated anwser.